# Уволен из или с предприятия?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Как правильно написать: уволен *из* предприятия или *с*?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы выбрать правильный предлог, необходимо вспомнить, *с* или *из* употребляется с каждым конкретным словом: мы говорим *(идти) **на** предприятие*, а следовательно, обратный предлог – ***с***.

Значит, правильно:

> Он был уволен **с** предприятия.

Некоторые другие примеры:

> уволен:
>
> - **из** института, **из** армии, **из** магазина;
> - **с** завода, **с** государственной службы, **с** работы.